# How to remove `AVIRA` antivirus program after windows upgraded from 8.1 to 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, avira

I have `Windows 8.1` and upgraded it in-place to `Windows 10`. I have installed `Avira`, but now I am getting constantly the following message:

[image]

The issue is that I have try clicking each option but the message keeps showing. I have try to uninstall the `Avira` from `Control Panel` but it's not listed there.

How to resolve issue?

Comment: https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/88

Comment: @Tetsujin It is not listed there, too

Comment: What isn't?? - there's every version & every OS... conventional & manual.

Comment: Install a version that is compatible with Windows 10 but the incompatible version was already not migrated when you performed the upgrade